# DateRangePicker - Selected date range not getting correctly highlighted

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, daterangepicker

```js
$("input[name='MyDaterange']").daterangepicker({
  ranges: {
    'This Week': [moment().day("Sunday"), moment().day("Saturday")],
    'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
    'This Year': [moment().startOf('year'), moment().endOf('year')],
    'Year to Date': [moment().startOf('year'), moment()]
  },
  maxDate: moment() // this is required
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<input type="text" name="MyDaterange" id="MyDaterange" value="" />
```

I am using daterangepicker for selecting predefined dates. When I select **Year To Date** another option **This Year** gets highlighted.

1. How to make only that range active which was clicked.
2. Is this a bug with daterangepicker?

> Code:

```
$("input[name='MyDaterange']").daterangepicker({
  ranges: {
    'This Week': [moment().day("Sunday"), moment().day("Saturday")],
    'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
    'This Year': [moment().startOf('year'), moment().endOf('year')],
    'Year to Date': [moment().startOf('year'), moment()]
  },
  maxDate: moment() // this is required
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you added `maxDate: moment()` it means, all dates after today is not counted, it means:

- when you select `This Year' , you will get  from jan 01 to today .
- when you select `Year to Date' , you will get  from jan 01 to today .

They are the same, and since the plugin check the start and the end date to check for activated range, 'This year' would always the first activated.

Solution:

- remove 'this year' since you use maxDate = today, it's not really useful

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this. Unfortunately I can't remove that option because all those options are standard across all pages in my website. I was wondering why can't only that range(label) get selected which was clicked rather than picking 1st one.

Comment: @Help That's the code. take a look on their code at https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker/blob/master/daterangepicker.js (L: 1332 to 1336) . Why do you use maxDate to today? atleast tomorrow and it would work.

Comment: Users are not allowed to select future dates hence maxDate today.

Comment: So 'year to date' and 'this year' mean the same dates

Comment: Agree with you but in some screen we do allow future dates so we have this standard options for all the screens. The true difference exists on those screen with future date allowed.